# Where to find World Latitude and Longitude Grid (arctic circle, equator, tropics..) in shapefile/ e00?

Tags: shapefile, latitude-longitude

i was wondering if you could teach me how to find World Latitude and Longitude Grid (arctic circle, equator, tropics..) in shapefile/ e00? I saw some of these datas affiliated with universities but unfortunately i am not one of their students.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Natural Earth](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/) has these lines look for Geographic lines and Graticules under Physical (not my first guess). The data is free for all possible uses.

Comment: I HAVE GOT IT!!! Thx for your reply! :)